# Problems with CMake whilst building OpenCV

Tags: gcc, image-processing, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to build the most recent version of OpenCV on a minimal enough VPS but am running into trouble with CMake. I'm not familiar with CMake so I'm finding it difficult to interpret the log output and thus how to proceed to debug the problem.

From the command line (x11 isn't installed) and within devel/OpenCV/-2.3.1/release I issue the following

```
sudo cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

and the result of this is the following:

```
-- Extracting svn version, please wait...
-- SVNVERSION: exported
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 44 (404)
-- Could NOT find ZLIB  (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find ZLIB  (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find PNG  (missing:  PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find TIFF  (missing:  TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find JPEG  (missing:  JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR)
--     Use NumPy headers from: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy-1.6.1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/numpy/core/include
--     Found Sphinx 0.6.6: /usr/bin/sphinx-build
-- Parsing 'cvconfig.h.cmake'
--
-- General configuration for opencv 2.3.1 =====================================
--
--     Built as dynamic libs?:     YES
--     Compiler:                   /usr/bin/c++
--     C++ flags (Release):          -Wall -pthread -march=i686 -ffunction-sections  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mfpmath=387 -DNDEBUG\

--     C++ flags (Debug):            -Wall -pthread -march=i686 -ffunction-sections  -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -ggdb3
--     Linker flags (Release):
--     Linker flags (Debug):
--
--   GUI:
--     GTK+ 2.x:                   NO
--     GThread:                    NO
--
--   Media I/O:
--     ZLib:                       build
--     JPEG:                       build
--     PNG:                        build
--     TIFF:                       build
--     JPEG 2000:                  FALSE
--     OpenEXR:                    NO
--     OpenNI:                     NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules: NO
--     XIMEA:                      NO
--
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                 NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                 NO
--     FFMPEG:                     NO
--       codec:                    NO
--       format:                   NO
--       util:                     NO
--       swscale:                  NO
--       gentoo-style:             NO
--     GStreamer:                  NO
--     UniCap:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                      NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                   FALSE/FALSE
--     Xine:                       NO
--
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                    NO
--     Use TBB:                    NO
--     Use ThreadingFramework:     NO
--     Use Cuda:                   NO
--     Use Eigen:                  NO
--
--   Interfaces:
--     Python:                     NO
--     Python interpreter:         /usr/bin/python2.6 -B (ver 2.6)
--     Python numpy:               YES
--     Java:                       NO
--
--   Documentation:
--     Sphinx:                     /usr/bin/sphinx-build (ver 0.6.6)
--     PdfLaTeX compiler:          NO
--     Build Documentation:        NO
--
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                      YES
--     Examples:                   NO
--
--   Install path:                 /usr/local
--
--   cvconfig.h is in:             /home/ec2-user/OpenCV-2.3.1/release
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Also when I run the command I also seem to be getting the following error message
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:44 (set_property):
    set_property given invalid scope CACHE.  Valid scopes are GLOBAL,
    DIRECTORY, TARGET, SOURCE, TEST.

Line 42-45 is the following:

```
set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Debug;Release" CACHE STRING "Configs" FORCE)
if(DEFINED CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set_property( CACHE CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE PROPERTY STRINGS ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES} )
endif()
```

However I'm not sure what this means? Does aNyone have any pointers?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your CMake version.  Support for `set_property(CACHE ... )` was implemented in 2.8.0.

If upgrading CMake is not an option for you - I guess it's safe to comment line #44. It seems to be used to create values for drop-down list in GUI.

http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/82

http://blog.bethcodes.com/cmake-tips-tricks-drop-down-list

Comment: Aha I seem to have version 2.6 of CMake. When I commented out those offending lines everything worked smoothly! thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced lots of error building opencv that were caused by the wrong version of OpenCV.  I successfully built opencv 3.0 using cmake 3.0 (though cmake 2.6 did not work for me).  Then when I found I had to downgrade to opencv 2.4.9 I had to go back to my system's default cmake 2.6, as cmake 3.0 did not work.  The first thing to check if you get errors when running cmake in opencv is the version.